# EloTouch touchscreen suspends correctly but does not come out of standby on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-10.04, x-windows, touchscreen, wake-up

I am using an EloTouch touchscreen on a minimal Ubuntu 10.04 installation. I have a bare Xserver running without any desktop environment, just an xterm. The touchscreen is working great, but there is still one small problem. As soon as the touchscreen goes to standby, it is not coming out of standby when touching the screen. Using a keyboard or mouse does get it out of standby though.

I am looking for any hints or directions to a cause of this problem. Is this an x.org configuration problem? A driver problem? Is this a known problem with touchscreens in general?
Any pointers are welcome. The driver I am using is an unreleased EloTouch driver (3.5.0). I received it through a reseller who can not give me any technical information unfortunately.

---

**Update:** I installed Xscreensaver, and configured DPMS through Xscreensaver. Now the monitor does wakeup upon touchscreen input. I am still not sure why this is required though.